# Render partial in Ruby on rails a collection is multiplying items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, renderpartial

I want to display a list of items in a page in Ruby-on-Rails. I use partials

in my `index.html.erb` file I have:

```
<%= @lista = News.find(:all, :order => Document::COL_DATE + ' DESC, id DESC')
    render :partial => "newsitem",
           :layout => "list_news",
           :spacer_template => "spacer",
           :collection => @lista
%>
```

in `_list_news.html.erb` I have:

```
<div class="news">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

in `_spacer.html.erb`  I have `<hr/>`

in `_newsitem.html.erb` I have

```
<%= newsitem_counter + 1 %>
<!-- Code to print details for one item -->
```

The problem is that it prints the list multiple times:

If the list has 3 items, it shows them 3 times: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3.
If it has 7 items, those items are printed 7 times.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: stick some logging in your view code to see what's getting called repeatedly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The :layout option is usually used with :action or a single :partial, not with :collection's. The problem: yield is being called for every item in the list.

You'd have to look at the sources to figure out why :layout and :collection are acting this way; but suffice it to say your code should probably just be rewritten so that it doesn't rely on :layout and :collection working together.

Here's one way you could do so, with the assumption that reusing this code in other views is a high priority. Unless you're using lots of caching, rendering each partial tends to be fairly slow, especially if your news_feed has many items, so I've consolidated it into one.

`controller/news_controller.rb`

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @news_feed = News.find(:all, 
                            :order => Document::COL_DATE + ' DESC, id DESC')
   end
end
```

`views/news/index.html.erb`

```
<%= render :partial => "news_feed",
       :locals => { :news_feed => @news_feed} %>
```

`views/news/_news_feed.html.erb`

```
<ul class="news">
  <% news_feed.each_with_index do |news_item, news_item_counter| %>
     <li>
       <%= newsitem_counter + 1 %>
      <%# Code to print details for one item %>
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If rendering a whole bunch of partials is okay for you running-time wise, you might find this implementation of `views/news/_news_feed.html.erb` nicer:

```
<div class="news">
  <%= render :partial => 'news_item', :collection => news_feed, :spacer_template => "horizontal_break" %> 
</div>
```

`views/news/_news_item.html.erb`

```
<%= newsitem_counter + 1 %>
<%# Code to print details for one item %>
```

`views/news/_horizontal_break.html.erb`

`<hr />`

So instead of rendering :layout, you render one big partial which wraps the collection.

Comment: This is what I was writing when I saw you post a response - and yours is more detailed than mine could have been.  +1.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I used the first method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem in Rails 2.3.8 and Rails 3! https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2279-render-layout-with-block-and-multiple-yields